# Multi-instance sharing of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, instance

Is it possible to share pointers between instances who don't 'know' each other?

I have a `Messenger` class, which parses strings and executes a command sent by the user. After parsing, it loads a `new DataBlock` to memory (data from files), executes the command on the `DataBlock`, stores the `DataBlock` to file and then deletes the `DataBlock` pointer.

I also have a visualization class, implemented in `DataVisualization`. This visualization also uses a pointer to the `DataBlock` class, but keeps the data in memory until the user closes the visualization. The program can also directly interact with the data of the `DataBlock`.

Issues arise when the `Messenger` loads the same `DataBlock` that is currently being visualized. The `Messenger` modifies the data on disk, but the `DataBlock` pointed to in `DataVisualization` has not been updated. When trying to modify the data of the `DataBlock` in `DataVisualization`, it tries to modify data on disk that might not exist anymore.

One solution I thought of is to use a 'lock file' on disk. As soon as one `DataBlock` is loaded from file, a 'lock file' is stored to disk. Any loading of the same `DataBlock` (based on identifiers) is refused as the `DataBlock` is already loaded in another instance. The 'lock file' is removed when the `DataBlock` is removed from memory.

I am curious how this can be improved, what methods are available to make the `Messenger` aware of a `DataBlock` that is already visualized through another instance, so it uses that pointer? If I use global pointers, it only works within the same program, how can I manage this with multiple program instances (let's say the visualization program is separate from the messaging program)? When thinking of database systems, which have to deal with a large amount of instances and large amount of queries, they can not keep everything in memory either or 'block' access to the database. How do they deal with this issue?

Comment: Too much verbiage without any code.

Comment: There is no perfect solution but you can (1) strive to keep the user informed, e.g. when was this data that you're seeing fetched, and (2) make sure that the stored data is self-consistent (which can include locking for modification). You might consider some notification mechanism for the views. E.g. they might subscribe to notifications.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you have two persistent objects which store their state on disk and you are trying to use both simultaneously?

Comment: If so, you could (a) use a lockout as you described;  (b) create a Manager for managing these objects. The only way to load and save an object is via the Manager, and the Manager would handle incoming object requests and synchronize the writing of object state.

Comment: Too broad and too many options/issues.  E.g. are your datablocks fixed size?  What do you do to "delete" them on disk (e.g. write a sentinel over the record / shift later datablocks in the same file over the deleted datablock / delete the file specific to the datablock)?  Do you have a free list or index to maintain on disk?  Do you want callbacks when datablocks are modified, or will you poll for updates?  How long can you afford to have threads blocking? etc.  If you're new to this, just pick up a database library and concentrate on your application code.

Comment: Sorry for the absence of code and the broad question, it might indeed have been better for a forum. It's very difficult for this kind of question to provide simplified code. 
@TonyD: As for the `DataBlock`, it's very flexible in size and uses multiple files as well. Deletion is removal of the file. Reading first happens only for data info (the header if you like) and when the program requests the actual data, it loads that data from file.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks for your suggestion, such Manager sounds like a  good solution. I will try to look into how they can be implemented using multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly share pointers between processes - each process has its own memory space, and the address from one process will not be valid/correct for another.

Perhaps you're trying to reinvent the wheel: You should be looking at [**Memory Mapped Files**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), [**Boost-Memory-Mapped Files** (maybe it's part of the STL in C++11 - haven't checked now)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html). A memory mapped file is essentially controlled by the OS and an interface is provided that allows sharing the resource between processes:

> A memory-mapped file is a segment of virtual memory which has been
>   assigned a direct byte-for-byte correlation with some portion of a
>   file or file-like resource. This resource is typically a file that is
>   physically present on-disk, but can also be a device, shared memory
>   object, or other resource that the operating system can reference
>   through a file descriptor. Once present, this correlation between the
>   file and the memory space permits applications to treat the mapped
>   portion as if it were primary memory.